# How to document simple Python script using Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-sphinx

I have gone through numerous Sphinx tutorials, but I still can't figure out how to make Sphinx document a simple Python script like this one:

```
def addNumbers(a):
    """This function adds one to the given number.

    :param a: The name to use
    :type a: int

    """
    b = a + 1
    print b

addNumbers(5)
```

Below are the steps that I make. What am I missing?

Install Sphinx:

```
pip install sphinx
```

Create a documentation directory within my project directory:

```
mkdir docs
```

Run `sphinx-quickstart` from inside of the new `doc` directory and hit Enter to answer every question except for these two:

```
Separate source and build directories (y/n) [n]: y
autodoc: automatically insert docstrings from modules (y/n) [n]: y
```

This makes my project directory structure become this:

```
myproject/ 
|-- docs/
    |-- build/
    |-- source/
    make.bat
    Makefile
|-- mycode/ 
    myscript.py
```

Open `conf.py`, uncomment the following lines, and add the path of the folder where my code is located:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('C:\myproject\mycode'))
```

Run the following command from my `docs` directory:

```
make html
```

Which gave me the following confirmation with no errors:

[image]

Now when I open C:\myproject\docs\build\html\index.html, all I see is the following and no info from the docstrings that I inserted in my original script. Clicking on Module Index gives a file not found error. Why is that?

[image]

**EDIT:**
After doing all the above steps, I added a folder `mypackage` and copied the file with my code in there making the directory content look like this:

```
myproject/ 
|-- docs/
    |-- build/
    |-- source/
    make.bat
    Makefile
|-- mycode/ 
    myscript.py 
|-- mypackage/ 
    myscript.py
```

I then ran the following commands from `doc` directory:

```
sphinx-apidoc -f -o source/ ../mypackage/
make html
```

Now clicking through Module Index gives me the following:

[image]

And clicking on `myscript` gives this:
[image]

Now the question is why is my main script myscript.py is listed under modules and not listed on the home page of the documentations?

Comment: Is there anything in docs/source?

Comment: Yes. Folders  _static and _templates, and files conf.py and index.rst.

Comment: I think its index.rst (which is `re-structured text`) that provides the index page maybe. Anyway, clicking on Module Index would maybe get you a list including `myscript.py`

Comment: Clicking on the link for Module Index give me an error "Your file was not found".

Comment: I added a folder `mypackage` under `myproject' and run `sphinx-apidoc -f -o source/ ../mypackage/` and then `make html`. Now I see `myscript` under Module Index under m. Is it how it is supposed to be? I thought `myscript` was supposed to be a part of the home page of the documentation.

Comment: No docs found. The manual says you may need autodoc, http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html#module-sphinx.ext.autodoc which is for docstrings

Comment: So I put exactly the same file with my script to both `mycode` and `mypackage` folders? Doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

An `__init__.py` file is required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages. See [Python tutorial documentation of packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

My guess is that `sphinx-apidoc` recognizes your script as a script, not a package, because you omitted a `__init__.py` file.  According to the docs for [`sphinx-apidoc`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/man/sphinx-apidoc.html#description):

> *sourcedir* must point to a Python package.

There's also a warning just below that in the docs:

> If you document scripts (as opposed to library modules), make sure their main routine is protected by a `if __name__ == '__main__'` condition.

Without seeing your code, I'd start with the `__init__.py` file and see if that takes care of it.

Comment: I added an empty `__init__.py` to the root of `myproject`, but now when I run `sphinx-apidoc -f -o source/ ../mypackage/` and then `make html`, I get an error `No module named mypackage.myscript` and `No module named mypackage`. Also, when checking consistency, it shows an error `\myproject\docs\source\modules.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree` and `\myproject\docs\source\mypackage.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree` Why is it?

Comment: `myproject` is not a Python package (it's just a directory), so remove `__init__.py` from there, and put one each in `mycode` and `mypackage`.

Comment: I removed `__init__.py` from `myproject`, and added it to `mycode` and `mypackage`. Still, when I run `make html`, I get the same errors that I described above.

Comment: At this point, I would suggest you create a public repo of the project, share it, and document the steps to install the project and reproduce the issue.